# DB2 audit performance impact

Tags: database, db2, db2-400, db2-luw, mdb2

Client requested to audit all user SQL statements to check who is accessing the data. We are going to implement `execute' audit policy.                 How much it will impact performance of the database??

Comment: You need to tell which platform you are on (and maybe which version). In general, I would expect a single digit impact. The impact depends on the type of workload, whether you specify WITH DATA, and more.

Comment: OS is Suse Linux 11.4 and database is db2 10.5. Yes we want with data option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overhead depends on the type of implemented audit policies, whether it is `WITH DATA` or `WITHOUT DATA`, and the available resources, and the type of workload run on the system.

To give an example, if you run an analytic workload with long-running queries and you want to log every statement, there is less **relative** overhead than in an OLTP system with gazillion short-running queries.

Overall I would expect single digit overhead. You want to run queries, not audits... :)